# Proving the existence of exactly six subspaces of $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^2$

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^2$ has exactly six one-dimensional subspaces.

$\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ has $5$ elements, so $\left(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\right)^2$ has $25$ elements, $24$ of which are non-zero. Every subspace must contain $(0,0)$, so I'm left with $24$ non-zero elements. Furthermore, if $W_1, W_2$ are distinct such subspaces and they share a non-zero element $v$ in common, then $W_1 = W_2$, as the subspaces are one-dimensional and closed under scalar multiplication.

This tells me that because $24/4 = 6$, there are *at most* six such subspaces, but it doesn't tell me that there are *exactly* six such subspaces. What am I missing?

Comment: Each line containing a vector $v\neq0$ contains the four different non-zero vectors $v,2v,3v,4v$ and no other non-zero vectors.

Answer (score 1):

*Every* non-zero element is in a unique non-zero subspace. If $W_1,W_2,\dots, W_k$ are your non-zero proper subspace. Let $U_i=W_i\setminus \{0\}.$

1. We know that each $|U_i|=4.$
2. We know the union $U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_k=(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^2\setminus\{0\}.$
3. We know when $i\neq j,$ $U_i\cap U_j=\emptyset.$

by the uniqueness assured in the first sentence.

Or you can find particular elements that generate different subspaces.

If $$W_{(x,y)}=\{(ax,ay)\mid a\in\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z\}$$

Show $$W_{(1,0)},W_{(1,1)},W_{(1,2)},W_{(1,3)},W_{(1,4)},W_{(0,1)}$$
are distinct subspaces.

Given any field $k,$ the non-zero proper subspaces are either $W_{(1,x)}$ for each $x\in k$ and $W_{(0,1)}.$

In particular, if $k$ is finite, then there are $|k|+1$ subspaces.

Answer (score 0):

We can explicitly construct the six desired subspaces; for them to be distinct their elements must be distinct, and since each subspace must contain exactly four non-zero elements these subspaces will perfectly partition the $24$ non-zero elements of $\mathbb Z_5^2$.

These subspaces are explicitly given by the generators
$$(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(1,4)$$

Comment: The brute-force method makes sense, but is there a way to know a-priori why these subspaces out to partition? It's clear that non-zero elements can't overlap, but do I know that they actually form a subspace (without checking it explicitly)?

Comment: @BradG. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379644/number-of-all-subspaces-of-a-vector-space-over-a-finite-field